# STL criterion for which algorithm have a copy version and which have not?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, standards, stl-algorithm

Some of the algorithms of the standard library have a `_copy` version and some have not. Is there any objective criterion behind this ? (for example why there is a `std::rotate_copy` but no `std::shuffle_copy` ?)

Comment: this is an area of opportunity!! you could contribute!

Comment: Given a reasonable (set of) use case(s), the standards committee would likely accept a small change like this from what I've seen in the past.

Comment: Is there a simple implementation of `shuffle_copy` that is more efficient than `copy` + `shuffle` and provides the same guarantee of *equal probability* of all permutations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the functions that have a `_copy` version are those where the work of the function could be combined with the work of copying, such that the operation could be done in one pass versus two.

This would not be the case for `shuffle` for example. There's nothing to be gained against doing a separate copy and shuffle as two operations.